# Join three tables by one foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, left-join, union

I have three tables:

```
Task (ID, TaskDescription)
Schedule (TaskID, ID, DueAt)
Audit (TaskID, TestID)
```

In `Schedule` table there is a list of scheduled tasks, and `Audit` table is for already done tasks. So first there is a row in `Schedule`, then when this task is done it's removing from `Schedule` table and added into `Audit` table.

Tasks table

```
+----+-----------------+
| ID | TaskDescription |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Clean room      |
|  2 | Remove trash    |
+----+-----------------+
```

Schedule table

```
+--------+--------+------------+
|   ID   | TaskID |   DueAt    |
+--------+--------+------------+
| 927847 |      1 | 2020-08-01 |
| 777777 |      2 | 2020-08-07 |
+--------+--------+------------+
```

Audit table

```
+--------+--------+
| TaskID | TestID |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      3 |
|      1 |      2 |
|      1 |      1 |
|      2 |      4 |
+--------+--------+
```

I need to take all planned and already done tasks for one task ID. So for example, what I expect as result:

```
+---------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+--------+
| Task.ID | TaskDescription | Schedule.ID | Schedule.DueAt | TestID |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|       1 | Clean room      | 927847      | 2020-08-01     | NULL   |
|       1 | Clean room      | NULL        | NULL           | 3      |
|       1 | Clean room      | NULL        | NULL           | 2      |
|       1 | Clean room      | NULL        | NULL           | 1      |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+--------+
```

That means already 3 tasks are done and one is scheduled for 2020-08-01.
What i tried:

```
SELECT
    TaskID = t.ID,
    t.TaskDescription,
    ScheduleID = s.ID,
    ScheduleDueAt = s.DueAt,
    a.TestID
FROM Task t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Schedule s
        ON (s.TaskID = t.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Audit a
        ON (a.TaskID = t.ID)
WHERE t.ID = '1'
```

But of course, I get the wrong result:

```
+---------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+--------+
| Task.ID | TaskDescription | Schedule.ID | Schedule.DueAt | TestID |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+--------+
|       1 | Clean room      |      927847 | 2020-08-01     |      3 |
|       1 | Clean room      |      927847 | 2020-08-01     |      2 |
|       1 | Clean room      |      927847 | 2020-08-01     |      1 |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+----------------+--------+
```

I'm going to use `UNION` for that but first wanted to ask maybe there is more right way how to do it.

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you.

Comment: there already was expected result, but thanks, i also added additional samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `union all` the `schedule` and `audit` tables and query `null`s for the missing columns. Then, you can join that result with the `task` table:

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.taskdescription, s.id, s.dueat, s.testid
FROM   task t
JOIN   (SELECT taskid, id, dueat, NULL AS testid
        FROM   schedule
        UNION ALL
        SELECT taskid, NULL, NULL, testid
        FROM audit) s ON t.id = s.taskid
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that using `UNION ALL` as @Mureinik suggested is probably your best option here, but just for fun, another alternative would be this.

If you added another entry to your audit table for each taskID with a TestID of 0 (sort of as a default whenever a new task is created), then it will allow you to join onto the audit table, without the need for UNION.

So your Audit table would look like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| TaskID | TestID |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      0 |
|      2 |      0 |
|      1 |      3 |
|      1 |      2 |
|      1 |      1 |
|      2 |      4 |
+--------+--------+
```

Then you can modify your query to join the schedule table as normal, but only where the audit table value is 0.

And finally, to keep it tidy, use `NULLIF` to hide the 0 for that TestID if you wish:

```
Select
    TaskID = t.ID,
    t.TaskDescription,
    ScheduleID = s.ID,
    ScheduleDueAt = s.DueAt,
    TestID= nullIF(a.TestID,0) 
from
    Task t
    inner join
        Audit a on 
            a.TaskID = t.ID
    left join 
        Schedule s on 
            s.TaskID = t.ID
            and a.TaskID = 0
where
    t.ID = 1
```

UPDATE: You will also need an additional `where` clause for when there is no scheduled task, to prevent an empty row returning:

```
where
    t.ID = 1
    and not (s.TaskID is null and a.TestID = 0)
```

Comment: thank you a lot for your effort, but my problem is that i cannot modify tables and add new columns/entries, because tables are provided by the software

otherwise i would rewrite whole table architecture and make only two tables - tasks and audit, and audit would have DueAt column